# Is retry handled from go client library for azure service bus?

Tags: azure, go, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm referencing to the client library in https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-go. I was able to write a simple client which listens to a subscription and read the messages. If I drop the network, after a few seconds I could see the receive loop exiting with the error message "context canceled". I was hoping the client library will do some kind of retry mechanism and handle any connection issues or any server timeouts etc. Do we need to handle this our selves ? Also do we get any exceptions which we could identify and use it for this retrying mechanism ? Any sample code would be highly appreciated.

below is the sample code I tried (only including the vital parts).

```
err = subscription.Receive(ctx, servicebus.HandlerFunc(func(ctx context.Context, message *servicebus.Message) error {
        fmt.Println(string(message.Data))
        return message.Complete(ctx)
    }))

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("FATAL: ", err)
    return
}
```

Comment: May I know why the -1 here please. It is in their github readme that if there is any query to post up here with relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the older library doesn't do a good job of retrying, so you'll need to wrap the code in your own retry loop.

```golang
func demoReceiveWithRecovery(ns *servicebus.Namespace) {
        parentCtx := context.TODO()

    for {
        q, err := ns.NewQueue(queueName)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        defer q.Close(parentCtx)

        handler := servicebus.HandlerFunc(func(c context.Context, m *servicebus.Message) error {
            log.Printf("Received message")
            return m.Complete(c)
        })

        err = q.Receive(parentCtx, handler)

        // check for potential recoverable situation
        if err != nil && errors.Is(err, context.Canceled) {
            // This workaround distinguishes between the handler cancelling because the
            // library has disconnected vs the parent context (passed in by you) being cancelled.
            if parentCtx.Err() != nil {
                // our parent context cancelled, which caused the entire operation to be canceled
                log.Printf("Cancelled by parent context")
                return
            } else {
                // cancelled internally due to an error, we can restart the queue
                log.Printf("Error occurred, restarting")
                _ = q.Close(parentCtx)
                continue
            }
        } else {
            log.Printf("Other error, closing client and restarting: %s", err.Error())
            _ = q.Close(parentCtx)
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This library was deprecated recently, but it was deprecated *after* you posted your question. The new package is here if you want to try it - [azservicebus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/messaging/azservicebus) with a migration guide here to make things easier: [migrationguide.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/main/sdk/messaging/azservicebus/migrationguide.md)

The new package should recover properly in this scenario for receiving. There is an open bug in the new package I'm working on for the sending side to do recovery [#16695](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/16695).

If you want to ask further questions or have some feature requests you can submit those in the github issues for https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reply. Yes I have seen the API has been changed. We are in the process of migrating to the new one and hopefully it will not change :) and go live